# Top column to display date and time

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to build a table with a top row to display the date.  would I join two tables together? or is there some way to make a top row that will display the date. Here's a link of what the output should look like:
[image]

```
CREATE TABLE holidays
(`Category` varchar(12),`Month` varchar(12), `day` int, `English` varchar (70));

INSERT INTO holidays (`category`, `Month`, `day`, `English`)
VALUES
('Other', 'February', 1, 'National Freedom Day'),
('Other', 'February', 2, 'Ground Hog day'),
('Other', 'February', 4, 'Rosa parks Day'),
('Other', 'February', 6, 'National Wear Red Day'),
('Other', 'February', 12, 'Lincolns Birthday'),
('Other', 'February', 14, 'Valentines Day'),
('Other', 'February', 4, 'International Condom Day'),
('Other', 'February', 15, 'Susan B Anthony Day'),
('Other', 'February', 16, 'Washingtons Birthday'),
('Other', 'February', 17, 'Mardi Gras'),
('Other', 'February', 18, 'Ash Wednesday'),
('Other', 'February', 19, 'Chinese New Year'),
('Other', 'February', 28, 'Ground Hog day'),
('Other', 'February', 16, 'Presidents Day');
```

Comment: not sure what you mean by 'a top row that will display the date.'

Comment: maybe show expected result for the given data?

Comment: So on February 17th you would want "Mardi Gras" displayed?

Comment: sorry they wouldn't let me add a picture.  I put a link to an image that the output should look like.

Comment: http://sp-cfsics.metrostate.edu/~ics325fa1524/topbar.PNG

Comment: achieving what you want does not involve DB - it's just a GUI matter

Answer (score 0):

```
select concat("Today's date is",curdate()), null, null, null
union
select *
from holidays
```

However, I'd strongly advise whatever front-end tool you're using to work out what today's date is; that's really a user interface concern, not something you get from the database.

Comment: I guess thiss will fail, as curdate() and holidays.category have diffrent types...

Comment: well here's the goal.       http://sp-cfsics.metrostate.edu/~ics325fa1524/dq3.PNG

Comment: When you say front end tool what do you mean by that?  I'm building this database with all the holidays to add to a html/php webpage that will display all the months holidays.